# Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator devices don't show up in Start dropdown menu until launched

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I accidently uninstalled Visual Studio emulator for Android, then restored it with system restore point and now it's devices don't show up at VS Start menu until I launch them from the Visual Studio Emulators for Android.

How to add it to start menu, so I can just launch the one I want with F5 without opening the VS Emulators dialog?

I tried to reinstall the emulator and devices, still no success. How to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did it by repairing Visual Studio (from the control panel / installer).

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio Set Up file 
click on Repair